# Is there a way to ignore combinational loop error in HDL code?

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog, verification, formal-verification

I am trying to formally verify a small module in a very big Project code. I have anayzed and elaborated the design. I cannot verify the small module because the tool gives me a "Found Combinational Loop" error.

I am quite sure that this small module is not affected by this Loop error. So i want to avaid getting this error. Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I have little experience of using formal tools, but I know that static timing analysers (also _static_) sometimes get confused or, more likely, find paths that you didn't know where there. Presumably it says what this path is? Could you perhaps add some dummy logic to break this loop? (even if you think it's a false path) And obviously, it's always best to blame one's code before one starts blaming the tool - I guess you're convinced the tool has found some false path?

Comment: If you have a combinational loop in your design, it's a major issue. So at first you need to fix this bug rather than ignore it or try formal verification methods on that buggy design.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor : At first, I plugged in my formal tool only into this small module and was successful in verifying it. Now i am trying to plug formal tool at higher Level and while doing so i get this error. The path that the tool is mentioning is correct one. But I am not allowed to Change anything in design(am an intern). So i wanted to know if i can mask it somehow and prove this module works as expected?

Comment: It sounds to me like you might have found a bug. If you're not allowed to fix it yourself, I suggest you need to go to the designer and show them.

Comment: I'm with @Paebbels. The point of formal is to find and fix defects that testing can't easily uncover. You've accomplished the first part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what tool you used, in JasperGold formal tool, you can use following command setting to break a combinational loop.

```
stopat u_DUT.signal_a
```

Just put it before `prove -all` in your tcl file (if you uses a tcl file to run your tool).

Have a look at `stopat` command in JapserGold manual for further information in your cases to see if you can easily break the comb loop.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Onespin tool. But this post led me to solve my issue.

Comment: No problem. Did Onespin provide a similar command to break the comb loop?

Comment: They have something similar with "cut_signal".